# Mod rewrite with two parameters ignore last

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess.

```
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ author.php?authorslug=$1&page=$2 [NC,L]
```

for my url it works only if both parameters are present

```
example.com/author/name-x/1
```

However if the second one isn't present

```
example.com/author/name-x
```

it throws a 404.

This is also prt of my htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*?)/?$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

How can I get it to work even if the second parameter isn't present?

Comment: Group what you want optional in parenthesis, followed by the question mark: `^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/([0-9]+))?$` and change `$2` to `$3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group in parenthesis all of what you want to be optional, followed by the question mark:

```
RewriteRule ^author/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ author.php?authorslug=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

Now that there's 3 sets of parenthesis you'll have 3 capture groups and variables. Our "make optional" group occurs second in the sequence of parenthesis so it populates the `$2` capture variable. And the actual value you want to capture comes third, so it's `$3`.

What you had there merely made the trailing forward slash optional `/?`.

Shorter yet:

```
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]+)(/([0-9]+))?$ author.php?authorslug=$1&page=$3 [NC,L]
```

Also, I noticed there is no trailing forward slash `/` in your example, so I took it out of the regexp.

Comment: I'm getting a sql error now? Exact same code just the change as you've mentioned above.

Comment: Yay, that means it works. Now on to figure out what in author.php is throwing an SQL error.

Comment: Not really :-) as it still works with two parameters but now throws sql error with one.

Comment: I ran a test here and what I provided is working with either one or two parameters. I'm guessing you need to provide for not having `$_GET['page']` set in your author.php file.

Comment: When it's set it's 1 otherwise nothing.

Comment: Really, this answer solves the question you posted. If you're having problems with an SQL query error in author.php then ask another, pointed question, so as to keep our stackoverflow neat and tidy. Peace, man.

Comment: I'll take your word for it! Thanks all the same